# How to get max value of claims value in ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.1

In my case the user may be in multiple roles, for example user may be Admin and SysAdmin.

In admin role he has a claim `("Employee.Add", "Allow")`, and in SysAdmin role a claim `("Employee.Add", "Deny")`. In my case this user must be authorized when try to add an employee.

How to get this using a policy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use asp.net core Policy's RequireAssertion method to achieve your requirement.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
        services.AddAuthorization(options => {
            options.AddPolicy("TestAccess", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            {
               // you could modify below codes due to your requirement
               var re= context.User.Claims.Where(x => x.Type == "Employee.Add").First();
                if (re != null)
                {
                    if (re.Value == "Allow")
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }));
        });
```

Then in the controller, you could use below codes:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "TestAccess")]
public class VacationController : Controller
```

More details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/claims?view=aspnetcore-2.1).